# How to create a common ID for 2 two groups that share members in common

Tags: r, record-linkage

I am trying to create a new ID for groups that should be linked together as they share common members. Example below shows the problem.

The first table tells me that dedupe id 1 has members 12,23 and 34

| Dedupe ID # | Member |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 23 |
| 1 | 34 |
| 2 | 56 |
| ... | ... |

While the second table tells me dedupe id 5 has members 12, 23 and 47. Noting that 12 and 23 are common with dedupe id 1 in the first table.

| Dedupe ID # | Member |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 12 |
| 5 | 23 |
| 5 | 47 |
| 2 | 7 |
| ... | ... |

As groups 1 and 5 overlap - I would like to ensure that members 12, 23, 34 and 47 are joined into 1 dedupe id, like below

| dedupe ID # | Member |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 23 |
| 1 | 34 |
| 1 | 47 |
| 2 | 56 |
| ... | ... |

@akrun, good question. Maybe the better way of doing this is to update table 1 so that dedupeid 1 maps to Member 47 (see example above). All of the other mappings in table 1 should stay.

Comment: What if the `D` was 5 in the second data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear this might succumb to multiple common members, and its iteratively appending to `dat1` is a bit inefficient at scale, but ...

```r
members1 <- split(dat1$Member, dat1$Group)
members2 <- split(dat2$Member, dat2$Group)
for (G in unique(dat1$Group)) {
  m1 <- dat1$Member[dat1$Group == G]
  incommon <- lengths(lapply(members2, function(m2) intersect(dat1$Member[dat1$Group == G], m2)))
  move2 <- subset(dat2, Group %in% names(members2)[incommon > 0] & !Member %in% m1)
  if (nrow(move2)) {
    dat1 <- rbind(dat1, transform(move2, Group = G))
    dat2 <- subset(dat2, !Group %in% names(members2)[incommon > 0])
  }
}

rbind(dat1, dat2)
#    Group Member
# 1      A      1
# 2      A      2
# 3      A      3
# 4      C      5
# 31     A      4
# 41     D      7
```

---

Data

```r
dat1 <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "C"), Member = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
dat2 <- structure(list(Group = c("B", "B", "B", "D"), Member = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: thanks r2evans - this fits the bill, datasets not large in size so the inefficiency is tolerable ... for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Group = if(any(Member %in% df2$Member)) 
            paste0(Group, Member) else Group)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   Group [4]
  Group Member
  <chr>  <int>
1 A1         1
2 A2         2
3 A3         3
4 C          5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach that I thought of

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  full_join(
    df2 %>% 
      left_join(df1,by = "member") %>% 
      group_by(id.x) %>% 
      fill(id.y) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      mutate(id.y = if_else(is.na(id.y),id.x,id.y)) %>% 
      select(id = id.y, member)
  )

Joining, by = c("id", "member")
  id member
1  1     12
2  1     23
3  1     34
4  2     56
5  1     47
6  2      7
```

### Data

```
df1 <-
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2), member = c(12, 23, 34, 56)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))

df2 <-
structure(list(id = c(5, 5, 5, 2), member = c(12, 23, 47, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```